# Find earliest reference to inequality probability of material implication exceeds corresponding conditional probability.

Tags: probability, inequality, logic

Background: It is now well known that the following identity holds for all events a, b in any nontrivial boolean algebra B, where P is any probability measure over B,  P(a|b) is the usual conditional probability, assuming P(b)>0, b#a =d b' v a&b is the usual material conditional boolean operator at a, b:

(1)                  P(b#a) = P(a|b) + Q(a,b)
where>
(2)                  Q(a,b) =d P(b').P(a'|b) > or = 0 ,

so that

(3)                 P(b#a) > P(a|b) ,

provided

(4)                  Q(a,b) > 0,

which is obviously so when

(5)                 P(a|b) < 1   or  P(b) < 1.

It is surprising that the above simple relation between two (among many) approaches to
evaluating probabilistically simple indicative inference/implication has been mostly ignored in the vast literature concerning implication algebra, conditional probability, and foundations of conditioning.  This is even more so in times past.
Among the exceptions have been Calabrese [1975] and earlier Popper [1963].

I have searched  Adams, D.Lewis, Stalnaker, Peirce, frege, Russell, etc., to no avail to find the earliest reference to at least the inequality of eq.(3).

My question is what is the earliest reference that anyones knows about the relation in eq.(3) ?algebra

Comment: I have never seen $#$ as an operator here.  What does $b#a$ mean?

Comment: It seems to be "the usual material conditional boolean operator ", so: $b\to a$ ?  Similarly, I'm thinking `=d` is means to be indicate "by definition", or $\overset{\rm def}=$ ? Maybe. @herbsteinberg

Comment: And so (1) can be derived: $$\mathsf P(b\#a) ~{= \mathsf P(b'\lor (a\wedge b)) \\= \mathsf P(b')+\mathsf P(a\mid b)\mathsf P(b)\\=1-\mathsf P(a'\mid b)\mathsf P(b)\\=1-\mathsf P(a'\mid b)+\mathsf P(a'\mid b)\mathsf P(b')\\=\mathsf P(a\mid b)+\mathsf P(a'\mid b)\mathsf P(b')}$$